# Есть ли какие то плагины у gulp которые бы выдавали бы warning (аналогично uglifyjs)?

Tags: javascript, gulp

То есть чтобы  в консоль выводились уведомления и номер строки где неиспользуемые переменные объявлены, код содержит опасную проверку и подобные рекомендации по устранению.

Comment: gulp-jslint, gulp-jshint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы так же сможете задать свои опции для конфигурации этих плагинов или использовать готовые модули для них. Например  [jshint-stylish](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jshint-stylish)

1. [gulp-jslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jslint)
2. [gulp-jshint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jshint)